# Copy files and directories and recompress them to a new location but keep the same directories

Tags: pyspark, bigdata, oozie

I am new to pyspark or python for that matter and I am trying to recompress a bunch of data that is partition by month, day, and hour.

The goal is to copy a month of data then recompress it from snappy to gzip and then place it in a new directory but I want to keep the same directories for month, day, and hour if that makes sense.
/home/2016/01/01/00/ --> /home2/2016/01/01/00/

I have something put together but right now it just dump all files out into the 2016 directory in the final destination. I was looking at doing this as an oozie job which may solve the directory creation part?

```python
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
sc =SparkContext()


recompress = sc.textFile("hdfs://home/data/2016/*/*/*/*.snappy")

recompress.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://home2/data/2016/",compressionCodecClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
```

Comment: So, where is `oozie` in your tags?

Comment: I have added the tag.